# Parsing data from exel with PHP

Tags: php, csv, xlsx

I try to make a simple function to get data from an Excel file (csv and xlsx)
this is the structure of the documents

- Date
- Title
- URL

After getting data from files the function will get the content of the url column and get his html content by  file_get_content()

The problem is the function support only csv files, and `file_get_content()` gets only the content of URL finished by a name of files :

Example  www.aaa.com/index.php

For this url www.aaa.com/index  it make an error :

This the code of my function :

```
function getFileFromUrlExel($file){
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if( $ext == "csv" || $ext == "xslx"  ){
        $fp = fopen($file, "r");
        $columnnames = fgetcsv($fp, 1024);
        while (true == ($columns = fgetcsv($fp))) {
            $row = array_combine($columnnames, $columns);
            if($row["URL"] != ""){ $content = file_get_contents($row["URL"]); }else{ $content = "no_content"; }
            if($row["title"] != ""){ $name = $row["title"]; }else{ $name= "no_name"; }
            file_put_contents("files/".$row["title"].".html", $content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidebar: Unless it's a personal project that you're doing for educational purposes, plenty of good projects exist to help you read csv or xls docs in PHP. One example: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: Ooh, if you can afford a little additional overhead, please investigate PHPExcel (https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) ... I'm sure there are better things to do than reinvent this wheel! :-)

Comment: i try to make it simple with no use of external class with php

Comment: xslx or xlsx? Regardless, as far as I know neither is csv so you wont be able to read it with `fgetcsv`. Furthermore Excel "csv" is inconsistent in different Versions regarding encoding and maybe also quoting/delimiter rules which makes it hard to "simply" read it. So if you want to keep it simple, reduce it to csv and prepare that it could break with "csv" files from different Excel Versions or use an existing library. For the other problem, I would assume the correct URI should be `http://www.aaa.com/index.php`. Otherwise you may try to read `index.php` in the local directory `www.aaa.com`